# Typescript - React, conditional callback prop type based on optional prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component which accepts an optional prop **isSingle** (boolean) and a required prop **onSelect** (callback).

If **isSingle** prop is used, I need that my callback to have a different signature

```
type IProps<T> = 
    {
        isSingle?: T;
    } & (
        T extends boolean ?
        { 
            onSelected: (option: string) => void; 
            isSingle: boolean;
        } : 
        { 
            onSelected: (option: string[]) => void; 
            isSingle: boolean;
        }
    );
```

I just wrote this and it works, but as you see I have to define multiple times **isSingle** prop, but also the complier assigns to it the following type **(T | undefined) & boolean**

How to properly implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a generic type, a discriminated union works better here:

```
type IProps =
  | {
      isSingle?: false;
      onSelected: (option: string[]) => void;
    }
  | {
      isSingle: true;
      onSelected: (option: string) => void;
    };
```

You can combine this with additional props as well, like:

```
type IProps = {
  commonProp: string;
} & (
  | {
      isSingle?: false;
      onSelected: (option: string[]) => void;
    }
  | {
      isSingle: true;
      onSelected: (option: string) => void;
    }
);
```

Comment: That's what I need, but one question: why have you put two pipes and in front of the objects instead only one pipe after the first object? shouldn't this be considered a regular OR statement as in JS: `var1 || var2`?

Comment: so I would see it as
`{
      isSingle?: false;
      onSelected: (option: string[]) => void;
    } |
   {
      isSingle: true;
      onSelected: (option: string) => void;
    }`

Comment: @BarbuBarbu It's just a style thing - leading pipes are allowed for union types and helps line things up consistently.  I ran the code through Prettier which formats it this way.

Comment: Hi @Retsam, I know it's bit late. But I got a similar problem. You see, the answer is working if we also specify the `isSingle` prop in the component like `<Component isSingle/>` or `<Component isSingle={false} />`. But what if we don't want to put the isSingle prop because we already have the default value for it in the component? You see this answer will not work, the onChange will not have the type for the `option` argument. I've spent probably weeks trying to figure this out but still haven't found the answer. Do you have any insight about this?